# Chrome emulated devices location

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

In Google Chrome or Chromium at the Developer Tools / Settings / Devices there is a list of Emulated Devices. In it, is possible to edit, add or delete itens.

**Where** in the filesystem of the operating system **this settings are located** so I can backup, restore or manually edit all at once?

*thank you very very much*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's located in preferences. More specifically, this file:

```
C:\Users\ **NameOfUser**\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ **Default**\Preferences
```

`Default` might be called `Profile X` where `X` is a number, depending on how many profiles were created or exists. (E.g. "Profile 2")

If you want to actually modify the file, you can open it up in Notepad and look for the phrase `customEmulatedDeviceList`

Comment: Deeply sorry for the delay. That answer is correct.

Comment: _Suggestion for a more complete, OS-independent answer:_

In `chrome://version` look for **Profile Path**. In the file explorer look for the **Preferences** file in that location. It is a JSON and the Devices List can be found under `devtools.preferences.customEmulatedDeviceList`

_Thank you very much!_